# Creating an Ubbi Dubbi translator in Java

Tags: java

I'm in an entry java class, and for one of my programs I am expected to create a ubbi dubbi translator, which ads a ub before every vowel and vowel cluster. I cannot figure out how to get my program to run correctly, and also am unsure how to make it exclude the extra vowel included with the cluster. I am not allowed to use Stringbuilder..

```
public void buttonPressed()
    {

    String lowerCase = "";
    String userInput = input.getText();
    Scanner words = new Scanner( userInput );
    String ubbiDubbi = "";
    //Splits up user input by line


    while (words.hasNext()) {
        //Converting to lower case.
        lowerCase = words.next().toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(lowerCase);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lowerCase.length(); i++) {
            if (lowerCase.charAt(i+1) == 'a'){
                    ubbiDubbi = ubbiDubbi + lowerCase.charAt(i+1);
             }

                else if (lowerCase.charAt(i+1) == 'e') {
                            ubbiDubbi = ubbiDubbi + lowerCase.charAt(i+1);
                }


                else if (lowerCase.charAt(i+1) == 'i'){
                                ubbiDubbi = ubbiDubbi + lowerCase.charAt(i+1);
                }

                else if (lowerCase.charAt(i+1) == 'o'){
                                ubbiDubbi = ubbiDubbi + lowerCase.charAt(i+1);
                }

                else  if (lowerCase.charAt(i+1) == 'u') {
                                ubbiDubbi = ubbiDubbi + lowerCase.charAt(i+1);
                }


                 else {
                     ubbiDubbi += lowerCase.charAt(i);

               }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this translator to work you basically just need to step through each character in the input and write it to the output.  In addition if the input is a vowel you need to write "ub" out first, except where the previous character was also a vowel.

One thing which is going to be handy is to be able to identify vowels.  Starting by writing a function for this is a good idea.  It could look like:

```
    private boolean isVowel(char c) {
        return
            c == 'a' || c == 'A' ||
            c == 'e' || c == 'E' ||
            c == 'i' || c == 'I' ||
            c == 'o' || c == 'O' ||
            c == 'u' || c == 'U';
    }
```

Now that's in place if you look at the translation, we want to step over every character in the input and write it to the output.   This could look like this:

```
    private String translate(String raw) {
        String translated = ""; 
        for(char c:raw.toCharArray()) {
            // some extra stuff needed here
            translated += c;
        }
        return translated;
    }
```

For the extra stuff you need to know if the current character is a vowel and whether the previous character was a vowel so we can add a little to do this:

```
    private String translate(String raw) {
        String translated = "";
        boolean wasLastCharacterVowel = false;  // 

        for(char c:raw.toCharArray()) {
            if(isVowel(c)) {
                wasLastCharacterVowel = true;
            } else {
                wasLastCharacterVowel = false;
            }
            translated += c;
        }
        return translated;
    }
```

And finally to ad "ub" where required you can check if the character is a vowel and whether the last character was a vowel:

```
    private String translate(String raw) {
        String translated = "";
        boolean wasLastCharacterVowel = false;

        for(char c:raw.toCharArray()) {
            if(isVowel(c)) {
                if(!wasLastCharacterVowel) {
                    translated += "ub";
                }
                wasLastCharacterVowel = true;
            } else {
                wasLastCharacterVowel = false;
            }
            translated += c;
        }
        return translated;
    }
```

With that in place you just need to hook up the button press action etc.  So it might look a little like this:

```
public class UbbiDubbi {

    private boolean isVowel(char c) {
        return
            c == 'a' || c == 'A' ||
            c == 'e' || c == 'E' ||
            c == 'i' || c == 'I' ||
            c == 'o' || c == 'O' ||
            c == 'u' || c == 'U';
    }

    private String translate(String raw) {
        String translated = "";
        boolean wasLastCharacterVowel = false;

        for(char c:raw.toCharArray()) {
            if(isVowel(c)) {
                if(!wasLastCharacterVowel) {
                    translated += "ub";
                }
                wasLastCharacterVowel = true;
            } else {
                wasLastCharacterVowel = false;
            }
            translated += c;
        }
        return translated;
    }

    public void buttonPressed() {
        String userInput = "";// = input.getText();
        Scanner words = new Scanner( userInput );
        while (words.hasNext()) {
            String lowerCase = words.next().toLowerCase();
            String translated = translate(lowerCase);
            System.out.println(translated);
        }
        words.close();
    }


    public static void main(String...none) {
        System.out.println(new UbbiDubbi().translate("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy aadvark"));
    }
}
```

adding the main method gives an easy way to test out the translation.  Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm pretty unfamiliar with arrays so I didn't even think about this. Only problem is I need it to read each word, which I had to split to new lines using a while loop. How can I make this so that it's able to read each line? Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: You can add that logic into buttonPressed() the translate method doesn't need to change.  I've edited the answer to include the Scanner in buttonPressed().

Comment: Yes, I just figured out that code by implementing the output into the while loop. Is there a way to make it to read each line instead of just the last one? Sorry for all the questions, I keep getting stumped.

Comment: Sure, you need to move your translation logic into the while loop.  Currently your while loop is terminating before you are getting to the translation logic.  The upshot is that your translation logic is only seeing the last value that was set to lowerCase